# Grid View Start new activity on image Click

Tags: android, gridview

I'm a new programmer and I need a way to start a new activity when an image is clicked in grid view. Everything I've tried doesn't work. Do you have any ideas? I need each Image to load a different activity. I have the grid working but just need it to change activity.

Java File:

```
package your.pacage.names;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher };
}
```

Answer (score 6):

in the given code you aren't setting any kind of onItemClickListener (on the grid) or View.OnClickListener on the individual imageViews... You need to do one or the other for anything to happen when you press on one of the grid view items.

To start a new activity from an activity: startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this, TargetActivity.class))

All together do the following in onCreate:

```
GridView yourGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.your_grid_view_id);
yourGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l){
        Class targetActivity = getTargetActivityForPosition(position);
        YourActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this, TargetActivity.class));
    }
}
```